# Out of range BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm getting a list index out of range error, and not sure why. My code is a webscraper to collect temperature data from a website. All worked fine for months, until recently.

I have a number of functions shown below as reference. The important one is `getDailyAve()`, which is where I'm getting the exception thrown.

Any thoughts or advice is appreciated.

```
import sys
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen, URLError
import webbrowser
import time
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np
import re
import csv
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

DATE_FORMAT = '%Y/%m/%d'

def daterange(start, end):
      def convert(date):
            try:
                  date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, DATE_FORMAT)
                  return date.date()
            except TypeError:
                  return date

      def get_date(n):
            return datetime.datetime.strftime(convert(start) + timedelta(days=n), DATE_FORMAT)

      days = (convert(end) - convert(start)).days
      if days <= 0:
            raise ValueError('The start date must be before the end date.')
      for n in range(0, days):
            yield get_date(n)

class SiteLocation:
  """class defining mine location parameters to lookup on weather search"""
  def __init__(self, city, state, zip, code):
    self.city = city
    self.state = state
    self.zip = zip
    self.code = code

def getDailyAve(url):
  url = urllib.urlopen(url)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(url.read(), 'lxml')
  form = soup.find("form",{"id": "archivedate"})
  table = form.find_next_sibling("table")
  rows = table.select("tr")[1:]

  time=[]
  temp=[]
  minutes=[]

  # handle no data case
  if soup.find(text="Archive data not available for this date."):
    print("Data not available, URL: '%s'" % url)
    return None

  # capture time and temps
  for row in rows:
    data = [td.text for td in row.find_all("td")]

    match = re.search(r"[+-]?(?<!\.)\b[0-9]+\b(?!\.[0-9])",data[2])
    if match:
      temp.append(match.group())
      time.append(data[0])
      minutes.append(data[0][-4:-2])

  common = Counter(minutes).most_common()[0][0]

  finalTimes = []
  finalTemps = []
  for i in range(0,len(time)):
    if minutes[i] == common:
      finalTimes.append(time[i])
      finalTemps.append(int(temp[i]))
  dailyAve = sum(finalTemps) / float(len(finalTimes))
  return dailyAve

def writeToCsv(list1, list2, list3, list4, list5, list6, list7, list8):
  with open('results.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    results = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    results.writerow(['T-SJ', 'T- RB', 'T-DS', 'T-JW', 'T-GB', 'D', 'M', 'Y'])
    for idx in range(0,len(list1)):
      results.writerow([str(list1[idx]), str(list2[idx]), str(list3[idx]), str(list4[idx]), str(list5[idx]), str(list6[idx]), str(list7[idx]), str(list8[idx])])

def buildURL(location, day, month, year):
  if day < 10:
    strDay = '0'+str(day)
  else:
    strDay = str(day)

  baseURL  = "http://www.weatherforyou.com/reports/index.php?forecast=pass&pass=archive&zipcode=" + location.zip + "&pands=" + location.city + "%2" + "C" + location.state + "&place=" + location.city + "&state=" + location.state + "&icao=" + location.code + "&country=us&month=" + str(month) + "&day=" + strDay + "&year=" + str(year) + "&dosubmit=Go"
  return baseURL

def main():
  loc1 = SiteLocation('Farmington','NM','87401','KFMN')
  loc2 = SiteLocation('Whitesville','WV','25209','KBKW')
  loc3 = SiteLocation('Rangely','CO','81648','KVEL')
  loc4 = SiteLocation('Brookwood','AL','35444','KTCL')
  loc5 = SiteLocation('Princeton','IN','47670','KAJG')

  start = '2016/08/31'
  end = datetime.date.today()

  dateRange = list(daterange(start, end))

  listDailyAve1 = []
  listDailyAve2 = []
  listDailyAve3 = []
  listDailyAve4 = []
  listDailyAve5 = []

  listDays = []
  listMonths = []
  listYears = []

  for idx in range(0,len(dateRange)):
    strDate = str(dateRange[idx]).split("/")
    year = strDate[0]
    month = strDate[1] 
    day = strDate[2]

    url1 = buildURL(loc1, day, month, year)
    url2 = buildURL(loc2, day, month, year)
    url3 = buildURL(loc3, day, month, year)
    url4 = buildURL(loc4, day, month, year)
    url5 = buildURL(loc5, day, month, year)

    dailyAve1 = getDailyAve(url1)
    dailyAve2 = getDailyAve(url2)
    dailyAve3 = getDailyAve(url3)
    dailyAve4 = getDailyAve(url4)
    dailyAve5 = getDailyAve(url5)

    listDailyAve1.append(dailyAve1)
    listDailyAve2.append(dailyAve2)
    listDailyAve3.append(dailyAve3)
    listDailyAve4.append(dailyAve4)
    listDailyAve5.append(dailyAve5)

    listDays.append(day)
    listMonths.append(month)
    listYears.append(year)

  writeToCsv(listDailyAve1, listDailyAve2, listDailyAve3, listDailyAve4,listDailyAve5, listDays, listMonths, listYears)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  status = main()
  sys.exit(status)
```

Here is the exception thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\weatherScrape2.py", line 147, in <module>
    status = main()
  File ".\weatherScrape2.py", line 128, in main
    dailyAve1 = getDailyAve(url1)
  File ".\weatherScrape2.py", line 61, in getDailyAve
    match = re.search(r"[+-]?(?<!\.)\b[0-9]+\b(?!\.[0-9])",data[2])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Is it possible the temperatures dropped below zero? In Belgium they did :)

Comment: Could you provide a stacktrace where the error occurs? Furthermore your code is rather error-prone: this is not good design (sorry).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem My code should account for below zero, but yes, they would have dropped below.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem traceback added. Could you make some suggestions on improving the code? Lots to still learn.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to handle situations when *there is no available data*. Here is one way:

```
# handle "no data" case
if soup.find(text="Archive data not available for this date."):
    print("Data not available, URL: '%s'." % url)
    return None
```

Also, I think there is a problem in the logic of getting the `rows`. I'd do it this way:

```
form = soup.find("form", {"id": "archivedate"})

table = form.find_next_sibling("table")
rows = table.select("tr")[1:]
```

---

Here is a complete snippet that I'm executing (for a single URL):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import Counter
import re


def getDailyAve(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')
    form = soup.find("form", {"id": "archivedate"})
    table = form.find_next_sibling("table")
    rows = table.select("tr")[1:]

    time = []
    temp = []
    minutes = []

    # handle no data case
    if soup.find(text="Archive data not available for this date."):
        print("Data not available, URL: '%s'" % url)
        return None

    # capture time and temps
    for row in rows:
        data = [td.text for td in row.find_all("td")]

        match = re.search(r"[+-]?(?<!\.)\b[0-9]+\b(?!\.[0-9])", data[2])
        if match:
            temp.append(match.group())
            time.append(data[0])
            minutes.append(data[0][-4:-2])

    common = Counter(minutes).most_common()[0][0]

    finalTimes = []
    finalTemps = []
    for i in range(0, len(time)):
        if minutes[i] == common:
            finalTimes.append(time[i])
            finalTemps.append(int(temp[i]))
    dailyAve = sum(finalTemps) / float(len(finalTimes))
    return dailyAve


print(getDailyAve("https://www.weatherforyou.com/reports/index.php?forecast=pass&pass=archive&zipcode=87401&pands=Farmington%2CNM&place=Farmington&state=NM&icao=KFMN&country=us&month=09&day=03&year=2016&dosubmit=Go"))
```

Comment: Attempted your changes, but am still receiving an out of range error. Updated code and exception are shown in my edit.

Comment: @Pete interesting, works for me, on which url does it fail?

Comment: Copy and pasting the code I have shown works for you? Interesting... Mine fails on https://www.weatherforyou.com/reports/index.php?forecast=pass&pass=archive&zipcode=87401&pands=Farmington%2CNM&place=Farmington&state=NM&icao=KFMN&country=us&month=09&day=03&year=2016&dosubmit=Go

Comment: @Pete please see the update - I've cut it down to calling `getDailyAve()` for the URL you've posted - prints `70.125` (note, I'm using `requests` instead of `urllib2`).

Comment: I made a new file with your exact code snippet, and have received the same error. It's throwing IndexError: list index out of range. This is on line 27, which is the re.search call.

Comment: @Pete could you please try upgrading BeautifulSoup: `pip install --upgrade beautifulsoup4` and try again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133491/discussion-between-pete-and-alecxe).